# String length in masm

Tags: inline-assembly, masm32

I try to ouput the string length of hello in cmd screen using the following masm code.
I create a function called `strlo` to compute string length.

```
.486
.Model flat,Stdcall
option casemap :none ; case sensitive


include \masm32\include\windows.inc 
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc 
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib

strlo PROTO :DWORD
.data
msg db "Hello",0

.data?
pr dd ?

.code
start:

invoke strlo,addr msg
strlo proc parm:DWORD
xor eax,eax
mov edi,parm
l1:
cmp byte ptr [edi] ,0
je l2
inc edi
inc eax
jmp l1
l2:
ret
strlo endp
invoke StdOut,eax
invoke ExitProcess,0
end start
```

When I run it, I get no output.

> F:\masm32>len.exe
>
> F:\masm32>

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that you have the definition of `strlo` in the middle of your code. It will execute where it is defined. Instead you should move it to the end and let your main code look like this:

```
invoke strlo,addr msg
invoke StdOut,eax
invoke ExitProcess,0
```

Answer (score 0):

Control begins at label "start" because you wrote "end start", then yields at "ret". "invoke StdOut,eax" and "invoke ExitProcess,0" never executed. To ouput the string length of hello in cmd screen you should alter like below:

```
strlo proc parm:DWORD
...
strlo endp

start:

invoke strlo,addr msg
invoke StdOut,eax
...
```